# JSON Extract or JSON Search in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in json format

```
[{"name" : "var1","data" : "val1"},{"name" : "var2","data" : "val2"}]
```

I want to check the data is val1 or not if name is var1

Comment: what is the mysql version?

Comment: Mysql version is 8.x

Comment: this data saved under the same column?

Comment: Yes the data saved under the column

Answer (score 0):

you can use the JSON_CONTAINS to access the MySQL JSON column

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(<json_column>, '{"name": "var1"}') OR
!JSON_CONTAINS(<json_column>, '{"data": "var1"}')
```